# Неправильное отображение превью таблиц в тексте ответа

Tags: дефект, таблицы, предварительный-просмотр

Неправильно отображаются таблицы на превью ожидания принятия правки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

На превью во время редактирования все работает as expected:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ссылка на вопрос:
[Функций событий столкновений: OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionEnter2D, OnCollisionStay, OnTriggerEnter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions)

Comment: @Danis спасибо, при беглом поиске не нашел.